# Can I enrich a Mule message from HTTP REST service

Tags: java, http, rest, mule

I have a Mule flow with a POJO as the current message payload. I would like to enrich the message by calling out to a HTTP REST service that returns `text/plain`. I've tried a few different methods, but each time get an error. My current flow looks like:

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each">

  <enricher source="#[message.payload]" 
      target="#[variable:agentCode]" doc:name="Message Enricher">

    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"
     port="8080" 
     path="ods.service/agent/agentCode/#[message.payload.getAgentEntityNumber()]" 
     method="GET" mimeType="text/plain" doc:name="HTTP"/>

  </enricher>

 <component class="za.co.sci.mule.agt.MoveVariablesToPayload" 
    doc:name="Move variables to message"/>

</foreach>
```

The component after the enricher just moves the variable values into my POJO. When I execute this I get:

```
An invalid return type "interface org.mule.api.MuleMessage" 
was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"
```

That doesn't make much sense to me, but I have tried turning off the transport transformer, and I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream 
cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Which kind of makes sense, but doesn't really help.

My question is, is it possible to enrich a message by calling a simple `text/plain` REST service? If so, how do I construct my enricher?

**Update**

Made the changes as per suggestion below and still the same. Full stack trace:

```
ERROR 2013-10-11 16:01:03,998 [[sci_silica_interface].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : An invalid return type "interface org.mule.api.MuleMessage" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-266
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. An invalid return type "interface org.mule.api.MuleMessage" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.xml.transformer.jaxb.JAXBMarshallerTransformer:122 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: An invalid return type "interface org.mule.api.MuleMessage" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"
    at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.jaxb.JAXBMarshallerTransformer.doTransform(JAXBMarshallerTransformer.java:122)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:411)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:363)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException: Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://localhost:8080/ods.service/agent/agentCode/12345, connector=HttpConnector
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the result of the `<http:outbound-endpoint />` into a variable you need first to consume the stream.

To do so you simply need to this to your enricher:

```
<processor-chain>
   http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"
 port="8080" 
 path="ods.service/agent/agentCode/#[message.payload.getAgentEntityNumber()]" 
 method="GET" mimeType="text/plain" doc:name="HTTP"/>
   <object-to-string-transformer />
</processor-chain>
```

Comment: Within the enricher? The compiler doesn't like that.

Comment: I've improved my answer based on your comment

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's still failing. I'm pretty sure the error is happening on the HTTP endpoint before it even gets to the `object-to-string-transformer` I'll add the full stack trace to the question.

Comment: I edited your code to add an extra object to string transformer within the HTTP endpoint. Seems that both are needed for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually gave up trying to use an HTTP endpoint. Instead I wrote a custom Java class which does the REST call and the enriching (it implements `Callable`). I included it in the flow using a `<component>` tag. I'm still convinced there is a more *correct* way, but can't find any examples, and this way works.